# Young adult book about a girl who goes to live with her dead mother's people, who are aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

This book is probably from the 70s or early 80s. A girl's mother dies, and she and her father go to live in another town with her mother's relatives. The town looks relatively normal at first, but the town doesn't seem to have any contact with the outside world.

Eventually she figures out the people are aliens and they've been repairing their space ship to go back to wherever they came from, and she is helped by an alien boy to escape. The aliens look human except they have a sort of jelly-like substance covering over their eyes. After she escapes she goes to her aunt's house, who she discovers has jelly-covered eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***The Other Place*** by Nancy L. Robison

> Jolene feels there is something strange about their new home, an eerie
>   sense of isolation in the valley - but her father begs her to try it,
>   and she agrees, sensing that he is content for the first time since
>   his wife's death. She is horrified by the fact that all of her
>   neighbors and classmates have jelly-filmed eyes, worried by seeing her
>   father dancing with other people in a midnight ring in the meadow,
>   baffled by the evasiveness of the one friend she makes. The answer:
>   everyone in the valley is from another planet, they are all preparing
>   to depart for their home world, and her father is going along because
>   - he reveals - her mother was one of the aliens. Then Jolene recalls that her mother always wore pink glasses, always had cold hands like
>   the aliens. She begs to go back to the city, to stay with her aunt;
>   she's magically transported there, and she discovers her aunt's eyes
>   are "glazed over like jelly," the story ends.

[Bulletin of the Center for Children's Books, Volume 32, June, 1979](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/12705/bulletincenterchv00032i00010_opt.pdf)